# OpenGL weird behavior when combining Roll Pitch & Yaw

Tags: c++, opengl, rotation, pitch

I am noticing some strange behavior in my openGL program. Basically it generates some shapes, and the main focus is to have the camera 'fly' around the world with functionality for roll, pitch, and yaw changing. I have everything currently implemented, but now when I roll, followed by changing pitch or            yaw, the scene follows a strange curve and flies out of view. In my code I maintain 3 vectors, `VRP` for the coordinates of the eye, `VPN` for the focus point, and `VUP` indicating the up direction of the eye.
The code for rotating I have is:

```
s_rotateAxis(VUP, VPN[0], VPN[1], VPN[2], 0.1);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
gluLookAt(VRP[0], VRP[1], VRP[2], (VPN[0] + VRP[0]), (VPN[1] + VRP[1]), (VPN[2] + VRP[2]),         VUP[0], VUP[1], VUP[2]);
```

with the other direction just having -0.1 for an angle. `s_rotateAxis` simply rotates a vector about an arbitrary point. So in the above code snippet, VUP is rotated about VPN by 0.1 degrees.
To yaw to the left the code is as follows:

```
s_rotateAxis(VPN, VUP[0], VUP[1], VUP[2], 0.1);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
gluLookAt(VRP[0], VRP[1], VRP[2], (VRP[0] + VPN[0]), (VRP[1] + VPN[1]), (VRP[2] + VPN[2]), VUP[0], VUP[1], VUP[2]);
```

Again, focus point is rotated about VUP 0.1 degrees, and a point to look at is generated in gluLookAt. Pitching up as follows:

```
productUP = xProduct(VPN, VUP);
s_rotateAxis(VPN, productUP[0], productUP[1], productUP[2], 0.1);
s_rotateAxis(VUP, productUP[0], productUP[1], productUP[2], 0.1);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
gluLookAt(VRP[0], VRP[1], VRP[2], (VRP[0] + VPN[0]), (VRP[1] + VPN[1]), (VRP[2] + VPN[2]), VUP[0], VUP[1], VUP[2]);
```

Here, xProduct computes the cross product of 2 points, giving a point perpendicular to both. In this case VPN and VUP. I'm hoping someone can spot my mistake easily as I'm just starting out with openGL, without me having to post the entire program.

Comment: Could it be that you mixed up position vectors and direction vectors? You up-vector is just a direction, right? Then rotating it around VPN looks not correct to me, since up will most probably not be normalized any more after the rotation.

Comment: Hmm, the thinking behind that is basically, VUP is the x,y,z of the final triplet in gluLookAt (a vector representing the up direction), and by rotating that around the focus point the scene rotates. I shall look around for a different method of rotation and see if that implementation helps, thanks!

Comment: I don't think that is necessary. Your general idea is totally ok. I would just rotate VUP around "itself" (aka 0,0,0) not around VPN.